# Hibernate Native Query

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, java-8

I want to write a native query 'Select * in from table' my repo. The table name is different from the entity name.

When running the query,

1 if I put the entity name it returns Table not found.

2 if I put the table name in query, I get Validation failed for query.

The queries are

```
@Transactional
    @Query(
            value = "Select * from " +
                    "TariffPacks r2 where r2.TariffID = :tariffId " +
                    "and r2.regionname = :regionname " +
                    "and r2.category = :category " +
                    "and r2.amount = :amount " +
                    "and r2.operator = :operator", nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<TariffPacks> findByTariffID_RegionName_Category_Amount_Operator(
            @Param("tariffId") Long tariffId,
            @Param("regionname") String regionname,
            @Param("category") String category,
            @Param("amount") Integer amount,
            @Param("operator") String operator
    );

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(
            value = "Delete from " +
                    "TariffPacks r2 where r2.TariffID = :tariffId " +
                    "and r2.regionname = :regionname " +
                    "and r2.category = :category " +
                    "and r2.amount = :amount " +
                    "and r2.operator = :operator"
    )
    List<TariffPacks> deleteByTariffID_RegionName_Category_Amount_Operator(
            @Param("tariffId") Long tariffId,
            @Param("regionname") String regionname,
            @Param("category") String category,
            @Param("amount") Integer amount,
            @Param("operator") String operator
    );
```

If I use "Select * from TariffPacks r2 ..., nativeQuery = true ", I get the error Tariffpacks doesn't exist.
If I use "Select * from RECHARGEDATAPACKS r2 .., nativeQuery = true", I get Validation error in Hibernate.

The entity :

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "RECHARGEDATAPACKS")
public class TariffPacks {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "RECHARGEDATAPACKS_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "RECHARGEDATAPACKS_SEQ", sequenceName = "RECHARGEDATAPACKS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long packid;

    private Long TariffID;
    private String operator;
    private String operatoralias;
    private String regionname;
    private String regionalias;
    private String category;
    private Integer amount;
    private String talktime;
    private String validity;
    private String description;
    private String billercategory;
    private String updatedOn;
    private String entryDate;

}
```

I have three questions :
1 How to make hibernate look for the table name (RECHARGEDATAPACKS) while using nativeQuery = true?

2 Can I write "Select * " in Hibernate without using nativeQuery = true? I think I  have to write all the column names like TariffId, Operator, region .., but I want the entity to be returned. How to map all the columns to an entity in output?

3 Is there any other way to write individual column names and map them to an entity class? Like if I write Select TariffId, Operator, region .., how can I fetch the tariffId directly?

Comment: You must use the table name. How does the validation error look like?

Comment: It works now with the table name instead of entity name, don't know why it kept throwing errors.

Comment: Ist your question answered then?

Comment: yes, but the other questions are still there.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli 
The hibernate error which I am getting intermittently is : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [Delete from com.telecomwatch.process.entity.TariffPacks r2 where r2.TariffID = :tariffId and r2.regionname = :regionname and r2.category = :category and r2.amount = :amount and r2.operator = :operator] at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1607) at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 if I put the entity name it returns Table not found.**

If you are using **nativeQuery = true** then you have to write **Table name**.

```
    @Transactional
@Query(value = "Select * from " + "RECHARGEDATAPACKS r2 where r2.TariffID = :tariffId "
        + "and r2.regionname = :regionname " + "and r2.category = :category " + "and r2.amount = :amount "
        + "and r2.operator = :operator", nativeQuery = true)
List<TariffPacks> findByTariffID_RegionName_Category_Amount_Operator(@Param("tariffId") Long tariffId,
        @Param("regionname") String regionname, @Param("category") String category, @Param("amount") Integer amount,
        @Param("operator") String operator);
```

**2 if I put the table name in query, I get Validation failed for query.**

I tried with the same code and is working fine. please specify the exact error/exception.

**1 How to make hibernate look for the table name (RECHARGEDATAPACKS) while using nativeQuery = true?**

If using **nativeQuery = true** then you have to provide **table name** only, else you can write **HQL/JPQL with entity class name**.

**2 Can I write "Select * " in Hibernate without using nativeQuery = true? I think I have to write all the column names like TariffId, Operator, region .., but I want the entity to be returned. How to map all the columns to an entity in output?**

You can write like this:

```
@Query(value = "from " + "TariffPacks r2 where r2.TariffID = :tariffId " + "and r2.regionname = :regionname " + "and r2.category = :category " + " and r2.amount = :amount " + "and r2.operator = :operator")
```

**3 Is there any other way to write individual column names and map them to an entity class? Like if I write Select TariffId, Operator, region .., how can I fetch the tariffId directly?**

You can do like this:

```
    @Query(value = "select TariffID, category from RECHARGEDATAPACKS where packid = :packid", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> someMethodName(Long packid);
```

and then you can extract.

Comment: The issue seems to be that if I don't have the return type of delete to be of type void, this error is thrown. How can I reframe the query to get the count of rows deleted?

Answer (score 0):

When using native query you have to use the table name, not the entity name. You also have to use the database column names, instead of the java field names.

When using non-native queryies (known as JPQL or in hibernate specifically HQL) you have to use the entity and field names. Instead of `select * from Entity e ...` the syntax is `select e from Entity e ...`.

Comment: The hibernate error which I am getting intermittently is  :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [Delete from com.telecomwatch.process.entity.TariffPacks r2 where r2.TariffID = :tariffId and r2.regionname = :regionname and r2.category = :category and r2.amount = :amount and r2.operator = :operator]
 at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1607)
 at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)

Comment: The issue seems to be that if I don't have the return type of delete to be of type void, this error is thrown. How can I reframe the query to get the count of rows deleted?

Comment: For delete/update queries you can't use `getResultList` or `getSingleResult`. You have to use `executeUpdate`, because the result isn't rows, it's the number of affected rows.